# fnd_date.canonical_to_date function not working in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I have used `fnd_date.canonical_to_date` to convert a column to date data type.

```
the expected output is for example:29-JAN-2014
but i am getting : 29-JAN-0014
```

anyone knows why ?

```
l_actual_term_date varchar2(100);

 SELECT   to_char(ACTUAL,'DD-MON-RRRR')
           INTO l_actual_term_date           
           FROM per_table;

--assign to another variable as per reqmt of date type

prev_term_date :=l_actual_term_date;
--WHEN printed this will give 29-JAN-12

--then in another package have to aasign prev_term_date to a varchar type variable 

P_prev_term_date :=fnd_date.canonical_to_date(prev_term_date);

--when i print this P_prev_term_date i get - 29-JAN-0014 instead of 29-JAN-2014
```

Comment: Could you show how you use `canonical_to_date` ? And the relevant data so we can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux done-pls checkand tell

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code. You could try changing 'RRRR' to 'YYYY' and see if that makes a difference, but it's probably an issue with the 'ACTUAL' value being selected from the table.

Comment: Great question. I'm seeing a similar problem, +1

Comment: In type conversion questions it is helpful to include the exact types of the columns, variables and parameters involved, together with the relevant NLS settings for your session. `l_actual_term_date` is a string, but what are `prev_term_date` and `p_prev_term_date`? I'd never heard of `fnd_date.canonical_to_date` but it appears to be documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T462355.htm) as accepting a string "in the canonical date format" (though I can't see what that is - maybe some global setting?) and returning a date.

Comment: By the way, naming string variables `xyz_date` is probably asking for trouble, because they look like date variables when they are not.

Answer (score 3):

`prev_term_date` is probably a date variable, and your default date format is `dd.mon.yy`. What happens when you call `fnd_date.canonical_to_date(prev_term_date)` is an implicit conversion of `prev_term_date` to VARCHAR2, using the default date format `dd.mon.yy`; `fnd_date.canonical_to_date` then uses a date format of `dd.mon.yyyy` to convert it back to date, therefore misinterpreting the year.

Answer (score 0):

If ACTUAL column is a *date* type then use:

```
SELECT ACTUAL INTO prev_term_date FROM per_table;
```

If you need a string that represents *date* in canonical format do:

```
l_actual_term_date := fnd_date.date_to_canonical(prev_term_date);
```

I assume that `prev_term_date` is a *date* type.